# How to play downloaded files stored in device ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I download a file and stored it in my android device by using this code->

```
fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'music/' + file_name).then((entry) => {
  alert('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
}, (error) => {      
  // handle error
});
```

I am able to get the path of downloaded file i.e.

```
file:///data/user/0/com.my.app/files/music/test.mp3
```

and trying to play this file by using Media Controls Plugin and the code is here ->

```
this.playButton = 'true';
this.file = new Audio();
this.file.src = "file:///data/user/0/com.my.app/files/music/test.mp3";
this.file.load();
```

but this is not working for me, Can any one help to resolve this issue?

This problem is only with files stored in device, the url of any live music is working fine.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: No errros in console

Comment: Have you try to play audio from assets folder is that working ?

Comment: yes it is also working fine

Comment: Can you please tell me which plugin you are using?

Comment: cordova-plugin-music-controls

Comment: Are you referring to [Media Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/) ? If so here is [example usage](https://github.com/philipbrack/paystumped_ionic2fullapp/blob/master/src/pages/info-card/info-card.ts) If that is helpful.